# Why does Excel change the case of my custom worksheet function?

Tags: function, excel, uppercase, vba

Excel's built-in functions are styled with UPPERCASE characters. I'm a little OCD and like my custom worksheet functions to be UPPERCASE too, just like Excel's built-in functions. However, Excel 2013 (and earlier versions) sometimes changes the case of my custom Worksheet functions to CamelCase or lowercase, even though I always write them in VBA code as UPPERCASE. Is there a work around to fix this glitch? Why does Excel do this?

Comment: If you add any references to VBA project, then VBA code editor looks up for the methods and properties names in connected classes. AFAIK you can't change such behaviour, the only way I can suggest is to remove that references, and use late binding, without IntelliSense.

Comment: Do they match the names of existing Excel VBA functions? Shooting in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have at least found a workaround.

Once I have created my own custom built function, go into Excel and choose Formulas --> Defined Names --> Define Name. Then define the name of my custom function in the desired case. Apparently, what the name refers to doesn't matter.

This, of course, causes an expected error. However, when I call my custom function, it is now consistently upper, lower or mixed case as per the named range.

The second step is to choose Formulas --> Defined Names --> Name Manager and *delete* the custom function's name. Voila!

Now Excel formulas have the custom function names with the desired case.

Two problems remain though. First, I'd hate to burden my users with this "trick". Second, this still doesn't answer *why* Excel behaves in this way. Perhaps it's a clue?

Comment: Thanks!  As to the why, whatever you type it in as the first time you use it becomes the cached name for the function.  Your trick somehow forces it to recache the names.